# Get count unique values in a row in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
0     1        2
new   NaN      NaN
new   one      one
a     b        c
NaN   NaN      NaN
```

How would I get the number of unique (non-NaN) values in a row, such as:

```
0     1        2       _num_unique_values
new   NaN      NaN     1
new   one      one     2
a     b        c       3
NaN   NaN      NaN     0
```

I suppose it would be something along the lines of:

```
df['_num_unique_values'] = len(set(df.loc.tolist())) ??
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension.... with `set`:

```
df['num_uniq'] = [len(set(v[pd.notna(v)].tolist())) for v in df.values]
df

     0    1    2  num_uniq
0  new  NaN  NaN         1
1  new  one  one         2
2    a    b    c         3
3  NaN  NaN  NaN         0
```

---

You could do this with `stack`, `groupby` and `nunique`.

```
# df.join(df.stack().groupby(level=0).nunique().to_frame('num_uniq'))
df['num_uniq'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).nunique()
df

     0    1    2  num_uniq
0  new  NaN  NaN       1.0
1  new  one  one       2.0
2    a    b    c       3.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
```

---

Yet another option is `apply` and `nunique`:

```
df['num_uniq'] = df.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=1)
df

     0    1    2  num_uniq
0  new  NaN  NaN         1
1  new  one  one         2
2    a    b    c         3
3  NaN  NaN  NaN         0
```

---

**Performance**

```
df_ = df
df = pd.concat([df_] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df['num_uniq'] = [len(set(v[pd.notna(v)])) for v in df.values]
%timeit df['num_uniq'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).nunique()
%timeit df['num_uniq'] = df.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=1)
%timeit df['num_uniq'] = df.nunique(1)

196 ms ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
6.34 ms ± 343 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
679 ms ± 24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
3.21 ms ± 343 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: out of curiosity, which of the three approached do you think would have the best performance? That would be interesting to see. -- one step ahead!

Comment: @DavidL hope the edit addresses your question... am surprised the list comprehension was slower than I thought it'd be :-)

Comment: This one seems to be faster: df.nunique(1) - df.isnull().any(1).astype(int)

Comment: Yeah sure you can add

Comment: This is an overkill :) df.nunique(axis=1) would do the job

Comment: @Vaishali Hmm, my tests show it is still kinda slow. Are you getting the same results?

Comment: You are right, surprising its as slow as apply. Your solution with stack is by far the best.

Comment: Not true. It does. Make sure that they are NaN and not strings called NaN

Comment: What is your pandas version? Mine seems to ignore NaNs while counting unique elements (0.23.3).

Comment: @ayhan I realised I botched this up. nunique does indeed ignore NaNs!

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel yes thanks, my bad for not testing it out, and I've already commented and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 9):

Just use nunique(axis=1).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data={0:['new','new','a',np.nan],
     1:[np.nan,'one','b', np.nan],
     2:[np.nan,np.nan,'c',np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# print(df.nunique(axis=1))

df['num_unique'] = df.nunique(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

A more abstract solution:

```
df['num_uniq']=df.nunique(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not as fast as coldspeed's answer with `set()`, but you could also do

```
df['_num_unique_values'] = df.T.nunique()
```

First the transpose of `df` dataframe is taken with `df.T` and then `nunique()` is used to get the count of unique values excluding `NaN`s.

This is added as a new column to the original dataframe.

`df` would now be

```
    0   1   2   _num_unique_values
0   new nan nan 1
1   new one one 2
2   a   b   c   3
3   nan nan nan 0
```